# SmartTable Binding with OData service

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to bind SmartTable with odata service but table showing 'No Data'. My code as below:

```xml
<smartTable:SmartTable id="PersonSmartTable"
  entitySet="DataSetInODataService"
  tableBindingPath="Odata 2 Model Name definded in Menifest.json"
  tableType="ResponsiveTable"
  useExportToExcel="false"
  useVariantManagement="false"
  useTablePersonalisation="true"
  header="The Persons"
  showRowCount="true"
  enableAutoBinding="false"
>
  <!-- layout data used to make the table growing but the filter bar fixed -->
  <smartTable:layoutData>
    <FlexItemData growFactor="1"/>
  </smartTable:layoutData>
</smartTable:SmartTable>
```

In grid table I have used data binding code like

```xml
rows="{myODataModel>/DataSetInODataService}"
```

Can any one provide me sample code for this?

Answer (score 0):

A great resource for nearly anything "SAPUI5 standard" related is the SAPUI5 Explored app. If you search for "Smart Table" you will also find [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smarttable/code) sample.

There you will see they didn't use the `tableBindingPath` property but did bind the model to the parent view of the SmartTable (see the sample's `SmartTable.controller.js`).
The SmartTable then is smart enough to use your specified `entitySet` of your view's model.

If you defined your OData model in your `manifest.json` to be the standard model it should already be bound to your view and removing the `tableBindingPath` property should do the trick.

- manifest.json

  ```
  {
      "_version": "1.1.0",
      "sap.app": {
          ...
          "dataSources": {
          "localService": {
              "uri": "/",
              "type": "OData",
              "settings": {
                  "odataVersion": "2.0",
                  "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
              }
          }
      },
      ...
      "sap.ui5": {
          ...
          "models": {
              "": {
                  "dataSource": "localService",
                  "preload": true
              }
          }
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

If you don't want the model to be bound automatically you have to do this in your controller. Otherwise set the `enableAutoBinding` property to `true`.

Also make sure your service exposes at least the minimum required annotations in the `$metadata` (as in the above linked SAPUI5 Explored example).

- `$metadata` (defined in `metadata.xml` if using MockServer, compare Explored example's `metadata.xml:3938` )

  ```
  <!-- Default columns shown by Smart Table -->
  <Annotations Target="<Namespace>.<Entity (NOT EntitySet)>" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
      <Annotation Term="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.LineItem">
          <Collection>
              <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.DataField">
                  <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="<Property1>" />
              </Record>
              <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.DataField">
                  <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="<Property2>" />
              </Record>
          </Collection>
      </Annotation>
  </Annotations>
  ```

Comment: I have updated XML code and have removed 'tableBindingPath = Odata 2 Model Name definded in Menifest.json' section. Also I have added 'enableAutoBinding=true'. But still I can not see data. I have mentioned Model in 'manifest.json' and model can be accessible from controller because I can get model with this code 'var oModel = this.getView().getModel(MODEL NAME)'. @marcelbrueckner

Comment: If you want to bind a named model instead of the default one (which is the model "without name" (empty string) below the /sap.ui5/models path of your manifest.json) you have to bind it to the SmartTable control like so: `oSmartTable.setModel(oModel)`. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Probably problem is happening for `$metadata`. Now I have set model to SmartTable `var oSmartTable = this.getView().byId("PersonSmartTable"); oSmartTable.setModel(oModel);` but still it is showing No Data. I can see metadata in service if check with in browser url `HANA_SERVICES.xsodata?$metadata` but probably I need to do something more for annotations. It is not clear to me do I need to create `metadata.xml` file and need to load localy as you have shown? Can you please provide some link/code which can help me.

Comment: Please take a look at the `$metadata` I've added to my answer. You have to create the `metadata.xml` only if you're using a MockServer instance for simulating an OData service (like I'm doing it).

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are saying " You have to create the metadata.xml **only if you're using a MockServer instance**", does it mean as I am using SAP HANA server to generate odata services using xsodata so I **do not** need to create `metadata.xml`?

Comment: Correct. The MockServer uses the `metadata.xml` to generate the `$metadata` output. The SAP HANA server does generate the `$metadata` according to the settings of your service. As I'm not familiar with HANA I can't go further into details, unfortunately.

Comment: **Thank you for all your help**. It seems my code should generate data in smart table but somehow it's not happening and I am not getting any single complete example which can help me.

Comment: @marcelbrueckner I am struggling to find a correct solution for when I run my application manifest.json should able to figure out if it needs to call mock server in case my oData connection is not there and vice versa. If you want I can create a separate ticket and tag you there??

Comment: I will try my best :)

Comment: @marcelbrueckner - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809281/sapui5-mock-server-automated-fallback-config