# SAPUI5 - Mock Server Automated Fallback Config

Tags: sapui5

I am struggling to figure out a solution for a situation when I start my sapui5 application then based on manifest.json configuration application should start mock server when there is no connection for OData else call OData service. Right now I have  mockserver.html which start mock server and index.html for application.

Is it even possible what I am asking?

Thanks

Comment: [marcelbrueckner](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5995009/marcelbrueckner) - tagging you

Answer (score 0):

The mock server intercepts the URL you are specifing at mock server instantiation.
Simply check the availability of your OData service and if your service isn't available, you instantiate the mock server.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/util/MockServer",
    "sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel"
], function(MockServer, ODataModel) {
    "use strict";

    return {
        init: function() {
            var oDataModel = new ODataModel("<your OData URL here>");
            oDataModel.attachMetadataFailed(function() {
                console.log("Metadata load failed :(");

                /* Initialize mock server */
                MockServer.config({
                    autoRespond: true
                });

                var oMockServer = new MockServer({
                    rootUri: "<your OData URL here>"
                });

                oMockServer.simulate("path/to/metadata.xml", {
                    sMockdataBaseUrl: "path/to/mockdata",
                    bGenerateMissingMockData: true
                });

                oMockServer.start();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I didn't have any time to test my solution, but it should work this way.

Comment: What if OData service is available then how it comes out from above init function?I dont see what happens on success? Am I missing something?

Comment: On success, the `attachMetadataFailed()` function isn't executed and therefore no mock server is instantiated.